# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade laggy when wifi is on

Tags: wireless, 22.04, performance, xps

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. After the upgrade, the system is laggy—it randomly freezes for a split of a second. Sometimes, during a freeze, a key that I pressed only once repeats several times; the system is unusable for playing videos because the video freezes randomly every few seconds.

I have been trying to debug the issue by killing user processes and see if the performance improves. I also set the system to prioritize performance, but the problem persisted.

Interestingly, the problem was gone when I disabled the wifi. Immediately after disabling it, the freezes were gone, everything went back to normal and videos were playing smoothly.

I have been trying to find if anybody has the same issue online without luck. People complain a lot about performance worsening after upgrading to 22.04, but nobody is relating this to the wifi.

My laptop is a Dell XPS 13 with 16GB RAM.

This is the output of `journalctl -p 3 -b 0`:

```
Nov 19 09:13:37 XXXX kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000007b800000-0x000000007fffffff],>
Nov 19 09:13:37 XXXX kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 19 09:13:37 XXXX kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device: -5
Nov 19 09:13:40 XXXX kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
Nov 19 09:13:45 XXXX gnome-session-binary[1458]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Nov 19 09:13:45 XXXX gnome-session-binary[1458]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Nov 19 09:13:47 XXXX systemd[1369]: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Nov 19 09:47:31 XXXX kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
Nov 19 09:47:37 XXXX kernel: ACPI Error: Cannot release Mutex [PATM], not acquired (20210730/exmutex-357)
Nov 19 09:47:37 XXXX kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_MUTEX_NOT_ACQUIRED) (202107>
Nov 19 09:49:37 XXXX gdm-password][2272]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Nov 19 09:49:41 XXXX systemd[2284]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov 19 09:49:46 XXXX gdm-launch-environment][1316]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Nov 19 18:55:53 XXXX kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
Nov 19 18:55:53 XXXX bluetoothd[923]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Comment: Try running `journalctl -p 3 -b 0` just after you have experienced some freezes. This will list any errors from the logs with a time stamp. Not everything listed is a problem but it may steer you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you @PonJar I updated my question with the output of that command. I see lots of errors but they seem to have occurred at the start of the session, not during a freeze, and I don't see any error related with the network interface/wifi. These freezes are very short and frequent.

Comment: BTW, disabling wayland also fixes the issue. There seems to be some faulty interaction between wayland and wifi because the problem is fixed when I disable one or the other.

Comment: Which model of XPS?

Comment: XPS 13 (year 2016)